# What's the difference between this 2 code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 code which is a different and I get different answers. I wonder what the difference is

```
x, y = 0, 1

while y < 50:
    print(y)
    x, y = y, x + y

x=0
y=1

while y < 50:
    print(y)
    x=y
    y=x+y
```

first code output is: 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34

and two code: 1 2 4 8 16 32

Comment: Try working it through in your head. Assuming you're trying to compute the fibonacci numbers, the second doesn't work because `x` has been changed before you add it to `y`

Comment: In the second example it is equivalent to `y = 2*y`.

Comment: Please update the question with these sample outputs. Comments are not the place for these sorts of updates.

Comment: Yup, because one is the fibonacci sequence and the other is the sequence of all squares of 2.

Comment: Just a method how you update the value of 'y'. You are printing the value of y and still asking this question

Comment: If you debugged this then you would be able to tell us the difference!

Answer (score 6):

`x, y = y, x+y` constructs an tuple on the RHS using the original values of `x` and `y` before performing any assignments to `x` and `y` on the left. It's equivalent to

```
new_y = y
new_x = x + y
x = new_x
y = new_y
```

With

```
x = y
y = x + y
```

your new value of `y` is adding the *new* value of `x` ( which is `y`)  to `y`; you've already lost the old value. You would need to write instead

```
old_x = x
x = y
y = old_x + y
```

The tuple unpacking is a way to avoid the need for the temporary variable `old_x`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the order of evaluation.

In the first example, you have this:

```
x, y = y, x + y
```

This is evaluating two expressions on the right hand side, and then storing them into a tuple, then unpacking them on the left hand side.

Because this is all part of one "master" expression (the tuple), no variables are updated during the construction of the tuple. This means:

```
y, x+y evaluates as (old value of y), (old value of x) + (old value of y)
```

Once the tuple has been constructed, both `x` and `y` are set.

Your second example makes things explicitly different by putting the assignments into different statements. This causes the value of x to be changed before the computation of the second assignment:

```
x=y
y = x + y
```

This is equivalent to:

```
x = (old value of y)
y = (old value of y) + (new value of x == old value of y)
```

Which sets `y` to `2 * y`.